# Vuetify renders tags instead of class name

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using v card from vuetify but realized that when i did mine using the same markup, my "v-list-item" is render differently compare with the sample in code pen. Some of the CSS styles are not following too. Has anyone experienced this?

```
<v-card
  class="mx-auto"
  max-width="344"
  outlined
>
  <v-list-item three-line>
    <v-list-item-content>
      <div class="overline mb-4">OVERLINE</div>
      <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">Headline 5</v-list-item-title>
      <v-list-item-subtitle>Greyhound divisely hello coldly fonwderfully</v-list-item-subtitle>
    </v-list-item-content>

    <v-list-item-avatar
      tile
      size="80"
      color="grey"
    ></v-list-item-avatar>
  </v-list-item>

  <v-card-actions>
    <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
    <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101

[image]

Comment: Your code pen path is wrong.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Vuetify as the example? Do you not see console warnings about an *unknown custom element*?

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping your list item in a parent v-list component.

```html
<v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="344"

    >
      <v-list> <!-- NOTE THE PARENT COMPONENT!!! -->
        <v-list-item three-line>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <div class="overline mb-4">OVERLINE</div>
            <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">Headline 5</v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>Greyhound divisely hello coldly fonwderfully</v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>

          <v-list-item-avatar
            tile
            size="80"
            color="grey"
          ></v-list-item-avatar>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>

      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
        <v-btn text>Button</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
```

But all it does is add margin to the block.

Please update your pen. It's empty.